# Google Play + Admob Linked

Tags: google-play, admob, adsense, jdeveloper

My developers account got terminated but my Admob account is still in good standing.

My brother has a developers account, can I link my admob to his apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can link your Admob account to any developer account.

It does not matter who owns the developer account.

Comment: I had a developers account but it got terminated but I still have an admob account. If i link my admob to my brothers account want they terminate his developers account for being associated with a terminated developers account?

Comment: No. Admob account and developers accounts are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. You can link your google Admob account to any developer account.
But when your app is removed from Google Store, you shoud remove that app from Google Admob account.